# Use li instead select option

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

as you can see in the bottom code i create li to make list instead select option in html tag. but i get undesirable thing in appearance.

1. how to make li width same like bottom width. i have added value of width in css. the value 100% make li wider than bottom.
   [image]
2. how tom make caret and number inside li position float in right. i can add class pull-rigt to make it in right position but it make caret higher than text in left position (i want make them in same middle vertical position)

```css
.instead-option {
  z-index:999;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  max-height:300px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
 }

 .instead-option > li {
  width:100%;
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .instead-option > li > a{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .instead-option > li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
 }

 .instead-option > li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
 }

 .instead-option > li:hover {
  background: #aaa;
 }

 .instead-option > li > a{
  color:#232323;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <button type="button" class="form-control text-left nominal">Pilih nominal<span class="caret caret-right"></span></button>
   <ul class="instead-option list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="#">English <span class="text-primary pull-right">10000</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Deutsch <span class="text-primary pull-right">50000</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you have `position: absolute;` on `.instead-option` element, you can have another element wrapping with `position: relative;`.
2. You can use a small hack to position the caret both horizontally and vertically by using `top: 50%;` rule.

```css
.instead-option {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.instead-option > li {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.instead-option > li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.instead-option > li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.instead-option > li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.instead-option > li:hover {
  background: #aaa;
}
.instead-option > li > a {
  color: #232323;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-container {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-container .caret {
  position: absolute;
  
  /* Have the same padding to right as in the button*/
  right: 12px;
  
  /* Position the element from top by 50% of the parent element's height */
  top: 50%;
  
  /* Moves the element from its current position by -50% on Y axis to position the element vertically middle*/
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button type="button" class="form-control text-left nominal">Pilih nominal<span class="caret caret-right"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="instead-option list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">English <span class="text-primary pull-right">10000</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deutsch <span class="text-primary pull-right">50000</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @digilac3 thank you... you save my day. all answer can solve my problem. but how with the number (10000 and 50000). i want the position of number like caret. in right

Comment: @Dedi Replace `display: flex;` with `display: block;` on `.instead-option > li > a`

Comment: @digilac3 thank you very much. May your goodness get the best reward from the God

Answer (score 1):

You're using `position:absolute` on the `.instead-option` list. As such, `width:100%` is calculated independent of the containing div's `padding` value.

You can fix this by changing your css to match the padding on the col div

```
.instead-option {
    z-index:999;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    max-height:300px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    /* width:100%; */ /* REMOVE THIS LINE */
    overflow:auto;
    left:15px; /* matches column left padding */
    right:15px; /* matches column right padding */
}
```

Comment: thank you... you save my day. all answer can solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Below is your answer. Fixed both points, See additional css added at the end of css code .

```css
.instead-option {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.instead-option > li {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.instead-option > li > a {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.instead-option > li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.instead-option > li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.instead-option > li:hover {
  background: #aaa;
}
.instead-option > li > a {
  color: #232323;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Additional Css*/

.instead-option {
  width: calc(100% - 30px)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button type="button" class="form-control text-right nominal">
        <span class="pull-left">Pilih nominal</span><span class="caret caret-right"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="instead-option list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="#">English <span class="text-primary pull-right">10000</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Deutsch <span class="text-primary pull-right">50000</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's an expensive use of calc for an absolutely positioned element!